# Start C++ syntax highlighting for .cu (CUDA) files

Tags: emacs

I use Emacs as an editor. Of late whenever I use CUDA files (which usually have extensions `.cu`) I have to manually do `M-x c++-mode`  to turn on syntax highlighting and other yasnippet features.

How do I do I ensure that all `.cu` files when started in EMACS automatically borrow all the C++ mode features. In other words `.cu` extension becomes an alias for `.cpp` extension.

( I know there is a CUDA mode for EMACS, (not inbuilt) but when I installed this mode it does not turn on many of the useful features present in the C++-mode of emacs )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Putting this into your `.emacs` should do the trick:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cu\\'" . c++-mode))
```

Comment: Adding this produced lisp-error for me. What worked is `(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.ipp$"  . c++-mode) auto-mode-alist))`

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi: What was the error message? Maybe your version of Emacs doesn't have the `add-to-list` function enabled by default, though I don't see why that would be the case.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case people have missed it; there's a slightly more official `cuda-mode` available: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CudaMode

You need to put it somewhere in your `load-path`; for example on my Mac, I put the code in `$HOME/Library/emacs/cuda-mode.el` and added the following lines to my `.emacs` file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Library/emacs")
(autoload 'cuda-mode "cuda-mode.el")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cu\\'" . cuda-mode))
```

Comment: Why is it `"\\.cu\\'"` instead of `"\\.cu$"`?

Comment: because filesnames can contain newline characters you want to match "end of string" not "end of line", see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist for more details

Comment: If you just use MELPA and list-packages the above steps are not even necessary anymore http://melpa.org/#/